# What is the correct flag for do my homework questions?

Tags: discussion

What is the correct flag if any for questions that basically request us to do someone else's homework?
Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269809/write-a-simple-program-in-pl-sql-which-will-be-used-to-create-more-complex-qu)

I can't seem to find a duplicate of this question. Please flag as duplicate if you can.

Comment: Well first things first, homework questions are not off-topic and the close reason used is incorrect. The specific question is off-topic because it is too broad, it could potentially be answered any number of ways.

Comment: @bluefeet - Thanks for marking the duplicate, I couldn't find it. Yeah, if you read the off-topic description, it doesn't seem to fit. I normally flag as too-broad, but seeing the comment. I was more unsure than the usual.

Comment: They did offer money. Maybe they really wanted to hire someone from StackOverflow Careers? (I'm kidding)

Comment: @BSMP - Doesn't it sound like some sort of assignment for a competition or so? Speaking of not even glancing over the guidances before posting.

Comment: In cases like this, I usually link to [this article](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) in the comments as well as voting to close.

Comment: @bluefeet I understand your point on homework questions being to broad and not off-topic, but the help center says otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (number 3). Is the help center out off sync? Should I bring this up as a question here in meta?

Comment: @MaximoDominguez I'm not sure I agree it's out of sync. The help center states "_Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._" These are on-topic, if they include details, etc.

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding of it, but what I was trying to convey was that in the case of a homework question that doesn't include any details at all (which in my case was a test question in the review queue) when voting to close as off topic, there isn't an option that expresses the "homework question with no additional information".